# max length attribute is not working for hybrid application

Tags: android, hybrid

I am developing a hybrid application which is hosted inside a web view android container, My problem is max length attribute is not working for input type.

Comment: Please provide more code

Comment: What is it you're trying to do? Provide more details in your question.

Comment: I am trying to set maxlength attribute for input field type= number.$(".class").on('keydown keyup', function() {
  var $that = $(this), maxlength = $that.attr('maxlength')
  //if ($.isNumeric(maxlength)) 
   if ($.isNumeric(maxlength)) {
   $that.val($that.val().substr(0, maxlength));
  };
 });

Answer (score 0):

Set maxlength property in html input tag and onkeyup and onkeydown events.

get the max length property in on key down and on key up events and clear if exceeds the maxlength value.

```
<input type='text' onkeyup='validateLength(this.id)' maxlength="20" />

    function validateLength(id){
     var maxLength=$("#"+id).attr("maxlength");
     //console.log($("#"+id).val());
     //console.log($.trim($("#"+id).val()));
     if ($("#"+id).val().length > maxLength-1) {
       event.preventDefault();
       var value=$("#"+id).val();
       //console.log(value.length);
       $("#"+id).val(value.slice(0, maxLength));
    }
    }
```